# Output as context html

Tags: aem, sightly

The Idea is simple, 
i have an unordered  list, because there is no **mod** i do the following

```
<ul data-sly-list=${foo}>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
 ${itemList.index== 3 ? '</ul> <ul>' : ''  @ context='html'}
</ul>
```

the output is some kind of strange the ul's are reverted.

```
<ul data-sly-list=${foo}>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>

<ul> </ul>

<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Can someone help me out with a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what happens here is that context'html' sees the order of the tag as wrong, and switch them around.
Did you try @ context='unsafe' instead?

I would have to do more testing to see if there is another way of doing what you are doing (which I guess is splitting the UL after the 3rd item)

but the 'unsafe' context is to be used when all the other context cannot do what you are trying to do.